# Logging in Windows Event Log in Unmanaged C++

Tags: windows, logging, event-log

I know that I can use `ReportEvent` method to write event logs in windows. But it seems to me that this method is useful for logging events prior to Windows Vista and 7 event log changes. For example, I don't think I can create a custom application log, set sessionID, ... using this library.

My other option will be using the `System::Diagnostics` methods like `WriteEntry`. This one has the features that I'm looking for, but the problem is that I can only use it in /clr mode.

My question is: is there any unmanaged C++ library for logging events to Windows 7?

Cheers,
Reza++

Comment: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: It I'm correct, it seems to be what I'm looking for with more features. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Luke: I'm not sure how I can use EWT to log to Windows Event Viewer. I could only make it work to output in an .etl file

Comment: I've only ever used the legacy API; I don't know anything about the new API other than it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Luke, the answer is [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364158%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). For writting to event logger, you can not use the legacy API and you should use the manifest-based providers.